# Is it worth installing Skyrim to the Xbox hard drive now that the texture bug is fixed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I know that Skyrim had a texture streaming bug on Xbox 360 when it first launched, but the patch a few weeks ago should have fixed it. Has anyone done testing post-patch to see how the game performs after being installed to the hard drive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have done some research for you,Xbox 360...and here are the links and brief summary...
Loading Skyrim on your HD overall now has improved texture,even after patch 1.2
but so far 1.3 seems to be semi stable 
" knock on plastic "
but the game still has issues post patches including 1.3
so over all Texture Improved but not perfect yet,same goes for Bugs and past issues.
so HALF a Cookie is better than NO cookie so far from Bethesda...

NOTE: not every gamer has noticed inprovements,since some had little to no problems to begin with,also FYI it has been reported that after playing for a while the textures do KICK in
for some players that had reported problems...
links below listing some of my sources...

comparison before patches for disk vs installed on 360

http://noble-press.com/2011/11/30/skyrim-patch-1-2-doesnt-resolve-texture-scaling-issue-

issue/   Texture issues AFTER Patch 1.2

http://www.product-reviews.net/2011/12/17/skyrim-patch-1-3-more-xbox-360-bugs-reported/

patch 1.3 info

http://www.bethblog.com/2011/12/01/skyrim-what-were-working-on/

official Bethesda Blog

hope this helped : )